# Internal microphone does not work

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-netbook, pulseaudio, microphone, aspire-one

I have an Acer Aspire One D250 with Ubuntu Netbook Edition 10.10. The internal microphone is not working. What can I do to fix this?

Audio Device: N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller

Answer (score 1):

This is [a known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/412862). You can follow the suggestion in comment #3:

1. Add the mentioned PPA to your system (using a terminal):

   `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev`
2. Update the package list:

   `sudo apt-get update`
3. Install the mentioned package:

   `sudo apt-get install linux-alsa-driver-modules-$(uname -r)`
4. Reboot and hope for the best.

Comment: did not work still have the problem but in the bug comments i read that it's a problem with the audio channels

Comment: It did not fix it, but I see in alsamixer there is a new capture device that was not there before.